# How to add xml text in existing xml file if my xml having same node twice

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

i have following xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
    <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="Data">
    <Query>
    <DataSourceName>DS1</DataSourceName>
    <CommandText>text</CommandText>
    </Query>
    </DataSet>
    <DataSet Name="table22">
    <Query>
    <DataSourceName>DS1</DataSourceName>
    <CommandText>New text2</CommandText>
    </Query>
```

i have to add following xml text after ending of first "Query" element  using Xelement and XAttribute
my first xml text to add is:

```
   <Field Name="CommunicationDataValueId">
    <DataField>CommunicationDataValueId</DataField>
    <TypeName>System.Int64</TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="DeviceMasterId">
    <DataField>DeviceMasterId</DataField>
    <TypeName>System.Int32</TypeName>
    </Field>
```

my second xml text to add after ending of second query element :

```
 <Field Name="Min">
          <DataField>Min</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Max">
          <DataField>Max</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int64</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
```

How to do it???

Expected output should be:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
            <DataSets>
            <DataSet Name="Data">
            <Query>
            <DataSourceName>DS1</DataSourceName>
            <CommandText>text</CommandText>
            </Query>
      <Field Name="CommunicationDataValueId">
            <DataField>CommunicationDataValueId</DataField>
            <TypeName>System.Int64</TypeName>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="DeviceMasterId">
            <DataField>DeviceMasterId</DataField>
            <TypeName>System.Int32</TypeName>
            </Field>
            </DataSet>
            <DataSet Name="table22">
            <Query>
            <DataSourceName>DS1</DataSourceName>
            <CommandText>New text2</CommandText>
            </Query>
      <Field Name="Min">
              <DataField>Min</DataField>
              <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="Max">
              <DataField>Max</DataField>
              <rd:TypeName>System.Int64</rd:TypeName>
            </Field>
```

can anyone help to solve this please!!!!!!!

Comment: can you share expected xml output

Comment: can you please tell me how to access the Second node <DataSet>,because it is repeated i dont know how to get it

Comment: @DeepakSaralaya i have updated my Question,please have a look

Comment: @DeepakSaralaya I have chnges here my output of xml file...and wat actually i have to do final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using XDocument

```
 var doc = XDocument.Parse("your xml string");
   //namespace
   var nspace = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;
    foreach (var item in doc.Descendants(nspace+"DataSet"))
    {

        var str = new StringBuilder();
        var str1 = new StringBuilder();
        str.Append("<Field Name='CommunicationDataValueId'>");
        str.Append("<DataField>CommunicationDataValueId</DataField>");
        str.Append("<TypeName>System.Int64</TypeName>");
        str.Append("</Field>");
        str1.Append("<Field Name='DeviceMasterId'>");
        str1.Append("<DataField>DeviceMasterId</DataField>");
        str1.Append("<TypeName>System.Int32</TypeName>");
        str1.Append("</Field>");
        item.Add(XElement.Parse(str.ToString()));
        item.Add(XElement.Parse(str1.ToString()));
    }
```

Comment: its worked for me,in each dataset node ,after query its appending

Comment: its not working with namesapce..i dont want to namespace to remove from my xml file

Comment: i have updated my question ,actually this is wat i want to achive,by mistake i have upload wrong one before this

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following API for [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154665%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - `AddAfterSelf`.

You can find each relevant `Query` element and call that method, adding the piece of XML you want to add.

Comment: no it not works..m facing problem because xml file having duplicate element

Comment: how to access second datasets node element

Comment: m not getting error,bt each time my text get added to first DataSet Node and not at second Node

Comment: You will have to add the code you are using so we can make sense of this.

Comment: I have Updated My Question,Please have a look